# Create line chart grouped by two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm trying to build a line chart with Chartkick that show the number sales by sellers in days, but I don't know how can I do this.

I'm already showing in a table the sellers name and your sales with this code:

```
@sales = Sale.where(created_at: DateTime.current.beginning_of_month..DateTime.current.end_of_month)

@sales_seller = @sales.joins(:user).select("user_id, COUNT(sales.id) AS total").group('user_id')
```

This returns:

```
+--------+-------+
|  Name  | Total |
+--------+-------+
| Jack   |    10 |
| Kevin  |     3 |
| Andrea |    11 |
+--------+-------+
```

How can I put the sales.created_at in this scenario?

My models

## Sales

```
belongs_to :user
```

## User (seller)

```
has_many :sales
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

I used `num_of_sales` as the column in sales which contains the number of sales, you must fix it based on your `Sale` model:

```
data = @user.joins(:sales).select('users.name as name, sales.num_of_sales').group(:name).sum(:num_of_sales)
```

It is grouped by user name, but maybe it is better to group by user_id.

To filter sales, just chain a where method:

```
data = @user.joins(:sales).where(.....).select(.....
```

Then you can plot as line with:

```
<%= line_chart data %>
```